# Activerecord relation with multiple string as keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to solve an issue.

I have a Product model with about 10.000 records. These records come from some online merchant feeds, and between the attributes I have the `category_name`.

```
#<Offer id: 1, external_id: "[\"000002151\", \"Caffettiera Bialetti Dama nuova 1 t...", provider_id: 1, product_title: "Caffettiera Bialetti Dama nuova 1 tazza", product_description: "Ricarica caffè: Caffè macinato; Tipologia: Caffett...", external_model: "DAMA NUOVA", sku: "000002151", mpn: "0002151", ean: "8006363021517", category_code: "MFF", category_name: "Macchine da caffè">
```

The problem is that category name is not unique for every mercant: for one merchant the TV category is a simple "TV LED", for another is "LCD TV".

In my dashboard I need to filter for a category and so I create a Category model. I have about ten categories, and every 'macro' category include a lot of `category_name`

Basically my category migration is

```
create_table :categories do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.text :subcategories, array: true, default: []
end
```

My category `TV & Monitor` has a subcategory attribute that is an array, and inside the array I have every type of category the external merchant defines for TV.

```
['OLED TV', 'LCD TV', 'TV', ...]
```

If I use

```
Product.where(category_name: category.subcategory)

irb(main):005:0> Offer.where(category_name: ["Mini Micro Hi Fi e boombox", "Radio", "Sbattitori"])
  Offer Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."category_name" IN ('Mini Micro Hi Fi e boombox', 'Radio', 'Sbattitori') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

The query return to me all the products. But I want to create a relation, I want that `category.products` return me all the products where the `category_name` is included in my `subcategories` array.

How can I do?

Comment: Can you copy your sql query that you get for `Product.where(category_name: category.subcategory)`?

Comment: @AntonTkachov added the query, the model name is Offer and not Product

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that mostly should work for you, but I haven't tested it on my own

```
has_many :products, :finder_sql => "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_name IN (#{subcategories.map{ |category_name| "\'#{category_name}\'" }.join(', ')})"
```

PS: To be honest I don't like your approach at all. Every time I see complex field in the database like (object/hash/array) it usually ends up very bad....

I would suggest you to go with some real association between products and category. Right now you have category names duplication and that looks very ugly. I would manage my `categories` as a `tree` having `parent` association with another category or blank if it's 'macro category'. And product will have an average `category_id`.

In such case your `Category` would have `has_many children` and `has_many :product, through: :children`

Comment: Thank you su much. I think to create the category model using a YML file or using a constant. Basically is a map between the merchant categories and my categories. I cannot have real association, categories are string and I don't have any control on the feed. So we need to add manually the strings to our category "array"

Comment: Yes, I get what your mean. What I advise you -- `Category` without `parent_id` is your categories. All feed categories you add like another category with `parent_id` set to your category (like `TV & Monitor`). They will be children of your categories. All product will have `category_id` of `Category` from the feed. Calling `parent` on it will give you your real `Category`. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: So you turn your `subcategories` array into child `category` (tree structure)

Comment: Here is a gem, that I've used for such things -- https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree

Comment: And to seed your `Category` model I would go with general seeds